# How to write a type that transforms T object into the same object excluding null, and undefined?

Tags: typescript

This is what I've tried so far:

```
export const purifyObject = <
  T extends Record<string, unknown>,
  K extends keyof T,
  V extends K = T[K] extends null | undefined ? never : K,
  P = { [VK in keyof V]: T[VK] },
>(
  object: T,
): P => {
  const keys = Object.keys(object) as (keyof T)[];

  return keys.reduce((pureObject, key) => {
    const value = object[key];

    if ([null, undefined].includes(value)) return pureObject;

    return { ...pureObject, [key]: value };
  }, {});
};
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgMZQHYGdEQK4wJYBmAngPIBGAViEogLwIA8wCCAKguHCKgCboIAlarB4NM%20VAHMANAmyoA1qigB3VAD5pzBAGkOYLr34KQRKATZaWANX2G%20uhPVYBtHQF073B6mwAbPwQAHzleEAI8VBAeBAB%20BCiANxAYBAAuXSsEAAUnBABvBBdrPUiEEzMLa3cM1xLPAF8tdQAKbShKajharQBKDNzadQLtFAxECv56cioaADpJlo7ZuF6EAEN%20ForzNl6XdwBuYG0YEDhcVHLTdDmznmwkEBaWnDOZrtkKtaGRlhYxpgEIl1n5sCA8ssui4KkcTv8EIQEC0XL4ArJ5DxwpFou45pEkGCsegWiCwSBemszhcYFc3iAPjRjtoWNTLgUEHMufTGXBZDDTDVgaDwQgGscWE0Cg1esdxcAgA).

```
const dirtyObject = {
    a: 1,
    b: null,
    c: undefined,
};
console.log(purifyObject(dirtyObject)); // { a: 1 }
```

I'm trying to get an object which can have values null, or undefined, and returns the type of the same object excluding the key-value pairs with values null, and undefined. How to write the type for that?

Following the above example:

```
{
    a: number,
    b: null,
    c: undefined,
}
```

Should return

```
{ a: number }
```

```
{ [key: string]?: string | undefined | null }
```

Should return

```
{ [key: string]?: string }
```

or

```
{ [key: string]: string }
```

Comment: Could you put some example usages. If you pass in `{ foo?: number | null }` what should the return type be? `{ foo?: number }` ? Excluding `undefined` doesn't seem to be what the function is in effect doing, since not adding the property means that accessing it at runtime would result in undefined and removing all properties that could contain `undefined` also isn't exactly what this function is doing

Comment: Edited the question with examples. The function does what it's intended to do. It removes properties with null, or undefined value.

Comment: Sa properties that can have `null` or `undefined` but also could have other types should be left in? It seems like a very narrow use case.

Comment: That's right. It's like filtering out falsy values from an array, but from an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mapped type with an `as` clause to exclude keys that contain `null` or `undefined`

```
type PurifyObject<T> ={ [P in keyof T as T[P] extends null | undefined ? never : P]: T[P] }

export const purifyObject = <
  T extends Record<string, unknown>
>(
  object: T,
): PurifyObject<T> => {
  const keys = Object.keys(object) as (keyof T)[];

  return keys.reduce((pureObject, key) => {
    const value = object[key] as never;

    if ([null, undefined].includes(value)) return pureObject;

    return { ...pureObject, [key]: value };
  }, {} as PurifyObject<T>);
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBACgrgJwJYDMQHkBGArCBjYAHgBUA+KAXgG8oBtGKJAOygGsIQB7FKYqAQwDOvegF0oEAB7AITACbCmcADbKoAHyhx5EFMwhyoAfihMIANwgIoALlii7xMVAC+AKDdSwnBMCh5OJkE-MERUDBx8PwooQjcoXglpWQUoACV8HzlCYOQmAHMAGi0mViZOAHcmUjdSAAp4qE5IgkdCtwBKO3hkNCxcAhJyCnIqRoCgv3YQYRj+qIA6acE65oHgDoFhOunuXg7aUQBuDwSECGBEFmWF87k4PAg6utDz+YJi6c2RqDGEhImwSg5n4yjg0BiayitGm4iEpgsVhOjQSqCgdVoSlUxW0cl0+jkogWzDwYLxKxBYIgHU250uCBYrwg72AyP+UDpV1+UAWvKZLOKMI4DmBoPBrhOCRcxSoLi2sDCfRaRDIHROLmRgL8ciQvgi60ov0a-DsAEZ2glMHYscoLf47Lj8WY5O0NW5lBcoJJDa9wiy6jq9Sy1VAAPSh7kmqCm1xAA)

Comment: Amazing, as clause is something I don't see often in this context.

Answer (score 2):

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDD0Cp2ACdoIQK4EsA2ATaBDAdtROyA9nkQGbQDWApgJ4DO0A7gBbIDGL07JALlshyN0yAE69a0AG5ZUiajHChgEgA7VoAETESA0nUYAeAPIAjAFbV2vaNQAevajnSMASlaKj0h+r1GCAcwAaAkocIiYcAD4o6ABeaABvGGgAbRpJQSo6cmgzS2sAXQAuPIsrXnS6QtsHJxdoHERUVGgAH3xnajJBakwAfmzJUpxqKWpRAG5gAF8q2lz8isLpsEhFaABZLFVoXhYNNUOiRuomPdp1WvY5ERwA6BFxSQzGMlEiAFtoAAMMxfK1h+zDYnEeRGojHCNh4OH4WSaLWgnk66G6vUwWEYMjkClg0AAcpDHJgltZGFhRBp6IhVKpPCS9kQiIplCpLhoAAqIfxkWgmQE2eyOZxuDxeHx+QIhHBhCLRWIJZLQNIZaBZACidhuiDRhn+FDJvCCWh0tH0DAFBV4MRKZWt8xqwvqYp4Et8-nuMrlkSiKRVg25vP5RsdsX90FKoYyhVmIHjsN80FUPOQfKN8WghhSABVaiKGu43d4PdLOj7okFgFEABQpIiC0o5qsASlKQbT-Jzitiyu4JCTr0zRoAdK8aw3rS3sIwawboDmW6kViAVVTeDy8K8R1T0Ih2NQazWU1SjSaMtO4r2I4mbDj5KVQuFIpnJxVHasVSq0zX7xo4gBjTNK0bQdH+8SAQQaI9KM6DTn2X7QOum7Jjy1BGhGMzxohyGiHgiQjoRJ7oYKJqOqUf4zNMKozCaiQzDO0Adnyhjdi20xUSAt6PGaGZKhGWClAAjFWiGmCMwGiV+7CPl0MF9FWnHANxVI0qgNgJCenZGjWTwSEa7FcQORCoNQI6oEQAQ1qpzS8NOoCgEkgnQEJWHslcAAambMfySQCaUpZehG6ASZ8pgTFJKriUBLSRdwsnQRicVkKUCFfs5gXBBGUUJeisFxVhMx+iAQA)

First you need build an union of keys which contains dirty value like so:

```
/**
 * Build an union of keys which contains dirty value
 */
type DirtyKeys <Object extends Record<string,unknown>> = {
  [key in keyof Object]: Object[key] extends null | undefined ? key : never;
}[keyof Object];
```

Then you can exclude these keys and use mapped types to build a new type like so:

```
/**
 * Map the type to new type excluding dirty keys from `keyof Object` which does not contain null or undefined as value
 * Nested Objects are supported too
 */

type Purify<Object extends Record<string,unknown>> = {
  [key in Exclude<keyof Object, DirtyKeys<Object>>]: Object[key] extends Record<string,unknown>
    ? Purify<Object[key]> 
    : Object[key]
}
```